# Expecting IllegalStateException, but getting reply from servlet container

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to practice Servlets concepts. I have written a sample code, which according to me should throw an IllegalStateException. But, I am getting the reply from the servlet container(Apache Tomcat 7). Can anybody explain what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

This is an example given in HeadFirstServlets. I think, this is an error in the book, page no 249. According to the API, the method should never invalidate the session. This is another example for inconsistent API.

**Code Snippet:**

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/SessionTest3")
public class SessionTest3 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("foo", "42");
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(0);   //Invalidate session immediately.
        String foo = (String) session.getAttribute("foo");

        if (session.isNew()) {       //should cause a runtime exception.
            out.println("This is a new Session.");
        } else {
            out.println("Welcome back!");
        }
        out.println("Foo = " + foo);
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the API for tomcat:

```
void setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval)

Specifies the time, in seconds, between client requests before the servlet 
container will invalidate this session. A zero or negative time indicates 
that the session should never timeout.

Parameters:
    interval - An integer specifying the number of seconds
```

Do you see why now?

Comment: Thanks for responding. It is actually "A return value of zero or less indicates that the session will never time out".

Comment: This method does not have a return value?

Comment: I am sorry. I saw API for getMaxInactiveInterval(). Thanks.

Comment: This must be an errata in HeadFirstServlets book, page number 249.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.  I don't have that book, but I wonder if it's a versioning issue?